# How to get last unchecked item in ngx-treeview?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular2-template, ngx-treeview

I am using npm module named as [`ngx-treeview`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-treeview)  . In this I can get the all selected items on change but not that one specific item which is getting changed. I am looking for uncheck.

In component.html file:

```
<ngx-treeview [config]="treeviewConfig" [items]="treeItems" [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate" (selectedChange)="onSelectedChange($event,$event)"></ngx-treeview>
```

In component.ts file:
First I have imported the ngx-treeview as

```
import { TreeviewItem, TreeviewConfig, TreeviewHelper, TreeviewComponent, TreeviewEventParser, OrderDownlineTreeviewEventParser, DownlineTreeviewItem } from 'ngx-treeview/src';


// function to be called
public onSelectedChange(downlineItems: DownlineTreeviewItem[], item: TreeviewItem ) {
   console.log(downlineItems);

   console.log(item);
}
```

Can anyone please let me know how can I get just unchecked item's value?